# How to use GStreamer in ASP.NET application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gstreamer

I want to develop an **ASP.NET** application using **GStreamer**, especially the **GStreamer Editing Services (GES)** module in the server end.

To do this I googled it and didn't find any detailed material about how to combine them together.
So I decided to try it myself.

- Firstly I downloaded the two installer files from [here](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/windows/1.9.1/) and successfully installed them on my **Windows 7** computer.
- Next I created a **C# project** in **VS2013** and tried to reference the DLL files in the `bin` folder of the installed SDK.
- Then I found that they are native DLL files and I had to P/Invoke them in my project if I need to use any function in the GStreamer library.
- Also I had to rewrite all the GStreamer classes I need in C# code because there is no way to export them from those DLL files, which requires me a lot of work.

This makes me wonder that if I'm on the right way.
Is there an easier way to let me use **GStreamer** in my **ASP.NET** application?

Comment: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/releases/gstreamer-sharp/0.9.2.html

Comment: @AlexK. Is there any material about how to use it? I did download [gstreamer-sharp-0.99.0.tar.gz](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/src/gstreamer-sharp/)  and found that it's a C# project, but I don't know how to incorporate it into my project.